# GCP cloud armor SQLI injection protection blocking valid POST

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I rolled out the Cloud Armor feature in front of a GKE cluster with the `sqli-stable` expression. For the most part, it works well. However, I started to get some complaints from users that feature in the application were throwing 403. What appears to be happening is particular POST requests with form data are getting caught in the rule.

It would seem by analysis that its rejecting array-based form elements i.e. a checkbox named `city[]` with a list of 8 or so cities.

I can of course re-architect the application, but I'd rather not touch it if possible. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view "blocked" request in HTTP(S) LB Stackdriver logging (resource.type="http_load_balancer") with status detail as denied_by_security_policy.

To fix this issue, you can manually adjust the policy, or remove the policy from the HTTPLB.

Cloud Armor pre-configured rules (WAF) consists of multiple signatures (CRS rule), if you believe a specific signature is blocking traffic that needs to be allowed, the rule can be [tuned](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rule-tuning) to disable noisy or otherwise unnecessary signatures.

Comment: Very useful comment. I followed the stackdriver logs. If you then expand the `enforcedSecurityPolicy` object you'll find the pre-configured expression ID (preconfiguredExprIds) that caused the DENY for me `owasp-crs-v030001-id941330-xss`. All the remains for me now is to figure out how to allow this rule for certain actions i.e. posting to AWS etc.